# Win8.1 machines have trouble browsing each other occasionally

Tags: networking, windows-8, dd-wrt, ipv4

I've got two Win8.1 machines. One is a desktop connected to the (dd-wrt) router through an ethernet cable, the other is a laptop that connects over wifi.

Both can ping each other just fine through IPv6, but oddly enough when I force IPv4 they both appear to ping some external IP belonging to my ISP. --Even stranger still, if I use Powershell's `Test-Connection` (a ping.exe replacement), the IPv4 address displayed is the correct one assigned on my internal network.

When I try to browse the other machine, one of three things will happen: everything works, everything *appears* to work but then Explorer blanks out for awhile while it tries to reconnect (or something), or Explorer eventually pops up an error dialog telling me the machine doesn't exist.

Finally, I can always browse the other machine by going directly to it's IP address instead of the friendly name.

Comment: Both are assigned a IPv4 address?

Comment: The desktop machine has a static lease, the laptop gets one through DHCP.

Comment: Static leased from the ISP or the router? Of it's from your ISP that explains why they can't communicate

Comment: From the router.

Comment: Have you tried where both have static ips?

Comment: Er. Well, no. I'll give that a go.

Comment: I forgot about this question. I still have issues, even with both having static IPs.